# How to retrieve a part of the data from Firebase Android

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

Contacts Fragment

```
ListView usersList;
TextView noUsersText;
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
int totalUsers = 0;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialogue;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

    usersList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    noUsersText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.noUsersText);

    mProgressDialogue = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mProgressDialogue.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialogue.show();

    String url = "https://messageplus-cd647.firebaseio.com/Users.json";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            doOnSuccess(s);
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            System.out.println("" + volleyError);
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    rQueue.add(request);

    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

doOnSuccess Method

```
    public void doOnSuccess(String s){
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

        Iterator i = obj.keys();
        String key = "";

        while(i.hasNext()){
            key = i.next().toString();

            if(!key.equals(UserDetails.phonenumber)) {
                al.add(key);
            }

            totalUsers++;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(totalUsers <=1){
        noUsersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        usersList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        noUsersText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        usersList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        usersList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , al));
    }

    mProgressDialogue.dismiss();
}
```

}
My Database strucuture - http://ibb.co/eMGhWb
I want to display only the names of the users. How do i achieve this.
with the current code, when i open the fragment It just says "Loading..." and doesnt load anything... do i have to do anything with exporting json file or anything? please help i'm still a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to query a Firebase database you only need to create a `DatabaseReference`, attach a listener and iterate over the `DataSnapshot` object like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arrayList);

        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
            arrayList.add(name);
        }
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be only tne name of the users.

Comment: can i get the code for showing it in a listview instead of Log please?

Comment: Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(anonymous com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener, int, int, java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>)

Comment: Change `this` with `getApplicationContext()`. See my updated answer. It works?

Comment: It's getActivity though... cuz im using a fragment...
anyways thanks a lot for baring with me... cheers